# Access to page timeline with depreciated offline_access

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I develop flash websites that feature posts from a Facebook page. Since I'm not accessing a visitor's account, I don't want them to go through the oauth process. I only want one feed in Json form, but that feed is a page and not a specific user. I've gotten around this by writing a script that I visit to grant an offline_access token. I use that token to access the one feed I need. On page load, I use the graph API Json URL to get the feed and parse the data in flash.

Now that offline_access is going away, I'm trying to find the best way to access the feed in raw json form that will work in flash.

I have read this page (http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), and can't find a scenario that helps me as all flows require a user to access an app of some kind. Does this change mean that I can no longer access a page feed without the process being transparent to the visitor? If need be I can be asked to be an admin of the pages I need access to, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That document](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) outlines all your options -

- If acting as the page itself you can get a token which won't expire - Scenario 5 in the document
- If acting on behalf as a user you need them to come back at least every 60 days – Scenario 2 or 3 in the document

Comment: Ah, I read that and did not think that applied to me as I didn't consider the sites I work on as 'pages' to the graph api.

From this documentation, I have to be an admin of a page(or direct an admin) to a script that redirects them to the endpoint in order to get a short-term token. Then follow scenario 4 to get a long-lived token. Then by querying the [User ID]/accounts I will get the non-expiring access tokens to all the pages that user admins.

Comment: Well, yes, but it sounds like your app doesn't need admin access to the page, if all you're doing is reading the page's feed, authorise your own app and refresh the token every 60 days, or use the App Access Token which never expires

Comment: Sorry Igy, one more question. How do I generate the Access Token for an app?

EDIT: Probably through this link (for those who found this page)...
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

I have to say the graph api is getting better and better. Everything used to feel really broken and kind of annoying to use, but it's really quite a robust system now!

Comment: Yeah, that's the instructions for an app access token